# does there exist a set $M$ of natural numbers satisfying conditions (i) and (ii)?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

> Does there exist a set $M$ of natural numbers satisfying conditions (i) and (ii) described below?

- (i) For any natural number $m > 1,\exists a,b \in M$ so that $a+b = m$.
- (ii) For any $a,b,c,d\in M, a,b,c,d > 10$, if $a+b = c+d,$ then $a = c$ or $a = d$.

I think such a set might not exist, and a good approach for proving this is by contradiction. So assume such a set $M$ exists. Note that among pairs $(a,b), a,b\in M, 10 < a < b, $ the difference $b -a $ is unique, because if two such pairs $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ had the same difference then $b -a = d - c\Rightarrow b + c = a + d\Rightarrow a = c\Rightarrow b = d,$ because $a < b$ by assumption. Define the number $q_n$ to be the cardinality of $\{a \in M : a \leq n\}$. Then ${q_n -q_{10}\choose 2}$ gives the number of distinct differences $b - a, a,b \in M, 10 < a < b \leq n$. But I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: When you say that $M$ is a set of natural numbers, do you mean that $0$ can be an element of $M$, or strictly positive integers?

Comment: You flagged this as contest math.  It’s important to identify the contest *in the question* (not in a comment) so we can confirm that it’s concluded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How prove can't exist a set $A$ of positive integers satisfying the two conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908521/how-prove-cant-exist-a-set-a-of-positive-integers-satisfying-the-two-conditio) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%2Bb%3Dm%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a%2Bb%3Dc%2Bd%24&p=1). Note I assume that by "natural numbers", you mean positive integers, like in the duplicate question.